# Spring: display static page before context initialization to enter datasource password

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a Spring 4.1.1 web application. Currently the datasource password is stored in a property file, in clear. Configuration is:

```
<bean id="mainDataSource"
      class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      scope="singleton"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass"><value>${jdbc.driver}</value></property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl"><value>${jdbc.url}</value></property>
    <property name="user"><value>${jdbc.username}</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>${jdbc.password}</value></property>
.
.
.
</bean>
```

My client doesn't want the password to be stored in a property file or, more in general, in the server.

The ideal would be to have Spring show a secure webpage to enter the database password.

The big problem is that I need access to the db to initialize the context and pretty much everything needed for the application to work. So the question is:

**Is it possible to have Spring display a web page prior to context initialization, so that the user can enter the datasource password? Perhaps through a filter or something?**

Please note to have the password encrypted in the property file or to have it passed as a parameter at Tomcat startup won't do, as it wouldn't be much different than having it in the property file, as regard to security.

Comment: The context needs to be fully initialized. Also if the client doesn't want it stored in a properties file but somewhere else then let it store somewhere else. What is wrong with a properties file anyway, set the rights correctly so that only the server can access/read the file (or a certain group of people) and you are perfectly fine. Or configure it in the application server as a JNDI property. Don't try to hack around it imho ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to set the database password into an environment variable, use the variable inside the spring configuration files, and then delete the variable after startup. This worked and seems to make the client happy.

To read the environment variable in spring_db.xml us this expression, if you have Spring 3.0 and above:

```
<property name="password"><value>#{systemEnvironment['variable_name']}</value></property>
```